# Autodesk Forge Error al intentar acceder al API en linea

Tags: c#, jquery, xmlhttprequest, forge

Tengo un problema al cargar un modelo 3D en un servidor en linea, el error que se muestra está relacionado con el acceso a el API de Forge, localmente funciona sin problemas sin embargo cuando se monta en el servidor o se hace un sitio web marca el siguiente error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)", seguido de "onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:7".
Como comento, lo que se me hace más extraño es que, localmente si funciona. Adjunto el segmento del código dónde muestra el error.

```
 function getAccessToken() {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", '/api/forge/token', false); //Dirección no encontrada
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Todo funciona en local. Deberias ver que la ruta es correcta, en localhost seria `localhost/proyecto/api/forge/toke` y en produccion seria `miweb.com/api/forge/toke`, en todo caso prueba poniendo toda la ruta

Comment: Ya lo intenté, pero lamentablemente no funcionó.  Gracias por tu comentario

Comment: Lo intenté nuevamente y ya funcionó! Muchas gracias. Me gustaría marcar cómo respuesta tu comentario

Comment: Bueno no se si la pregunta pueda merecer una respuesta, pero hare una respuesta un poco mas completa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno el problema puede ser que no este tomando la ruta correctamente, pues la ruta quedaría de la siguiente manera `miweb.com/proyecto/api/forge/toke`(esto si el script es ejecutado desde la ubicación de *proyecto*) esto en entorno de producción, recuerda en local todo puede funcionar.

Una posible solución para evitar este tipo de cosas es poner la ruta completa, por ejemplo `http://miweb.com/proyecto/ruta/api/forge/toke` seria la **URL** completa para acceder a la api.

Otra cosa que veo en tu código es que estas usando **XMLHttpREquest** lo cual ha sido utilizado por versiones viejas de *ECMAScript*, pues actualmente se utiliza una api nativa de js llamada `fetch`, esta es una tecnología *nueva* y en fase de prueba por lo que no es compatible con todos los navegadores (si usas Chrome no tendrás problemas).

```js
//enviamos la solicitud
fetch('/api/forge/token') //por defecto es GET por lo que no le pasamos el metodo
//nos devuelve un objeto Pomise
.then(res=>res.json()) //obtenemos la respuesta, mayormente la respuesta es un JSON
.then(res=>console.log(res)) //visualizamos la respuesta
```

Al utilizar la api `fetch` todo se vuelve mas fácil, cambiando la **URL** y usando fetch tu código funcionara perfectamente.